# bt.append(int(input(f"Enter burst time for process {i} ->"))) its the 11th line on my code when i run the code it shows invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

when i run the program for FCFS scheduling it points out an error at line

```
bt.append(int(input(f"Enter burst time for process: {i} ->")))
```

saying syntax error

```
    #python code to implement FCFS CPU Scheduling

n = int(input("Enter number of processes:"))     
bt = []     # Burst Time 
wt = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]     # Waiting Time
tat = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]   # Turn around time

#Take input

for i in range (0,n):
    bt.append(int(input(f"Enter burst time for process: {i} ->")))
#Waitng time
for i in range(1,n):
    wt[i] = 0
    for j in range (0,i):
        wt[i] += bt[i]

# Turn around time

for i in range(0,n):
    tat[i] = wt[i] + bt[i]
print()
print("\t Process \t\t Burst Time \t\t Waitng Time \t\t Turn around time")    

for i in range(0,n):
    print(f"\t P[{i}] \t\t {bt[i]} \t\t  {tat[i]} ")
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running? f strings were added in 3.6.

Comment: @Barmar python 2.7.16

Comment: You seem to be coding as if it's Python 3.x. E.g. you use `print` as a function and you try to use f-strings.

Comment: And you use `int(input(...))`. In Python 2, `input()` evaluates the input, so it will return a number, not a string, and you don't need to call `int()`.

Comment: I updated my pythons version and tried to re run the code and it worked Thankyou very much sir @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the format method:

```
"Enter burst time for process: {i} ->".format(i=i)
```